# Trying to add user details from Database on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I'm trying to add the user details from my database on the Navigation View of my Application. Anyone who can help me out? Here's a part of my MainActivity.

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    loggedName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loggedName);
    loggedEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loggedEmail);

    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
    loggedName.setText(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName);
    loggedEmail.setText(user.eMail);
```

I added the loggedName and loggedEmail on the onNavigationItemSelected. But the user details only show when I clicked an Item under this Navigation Drawer. :(

How can I automatically display the user details without clicking an item on the Navigational Drawer? :(

Comment: _I added the loggedName and loggedEmail on the **onNavigationItemSelected**_, _But the user details only show **when I clicked an Item under this Navigation Drawer. :(**_ , you have just answered your own question.

Comment: Anyone who can help me out on what should I do. Haha. I'm sorry, I'm new at this. :( @Dummy

Comment: what I mean is because you added the `loggedName.setText(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName);...` lines inside the _**onNavigationItemSelected()**_ method, it will set the text after the navigation item is clicked. if you don't want that, move those lines out of the callback method.

Comment: @Dummy Do you have an idea where I should put it? :(

Comment: move it to where as soon as you can retrieve the logged-in user (so that you do not get a null value) without having to select the navigation item.